# Export Data from Column A into a text file based on Column B

Tags: excel, vba, text, export-to-csv

I am looking to populate a number of SQL scripts using data from Excel.

In one column there is a list of usernames.
In an adjacent column, there is a list of locations.

I have a template of a SQL script, and I need a TXT file generated for each location, with the relevant users inserted.

For example, if this were the data set:
[image]

And this the script template:

LOCATIONA

update USERTABLE
set ACCOUNT_LOCKED = '1'
where USERID in
(%LOCATIONA_USERS%);

LOCATIONB

update USERTABLE
set ACCOUNT_LOCKED = '1'
where USERID in
(%LOCATIONB_USERS%);

The output would need to be like this:

LOCATIONA

update USERTABLE
set ACCOUNT_LOCKED = '1'
where USERID in
('User1','User2','User3','User4','User5');

LOCATIONB

update USERTABLE
set ACCOUNT_LOCKED = '1'
where USERID in
('User6','User7','User8','User9','User10','User11','User12');

It could either export to a single file, but with a separate script for each location, or a separate file per location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a similar dataset, with some formulas. You can inspire yourself on this in order to get what you need:

- Column A contains the names of the locations.
- Column B contains the names of the users.
- Column C filters on "LocationA", the formula is shown in C1.
- Column D filters on "LocationB", the formula (shown in D1) is similar to the one in C1.
- A `TextJoin` based formula is used for collecting the list of users, both for "LocationA" and "LocationB", the formula (`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,C2:C6)`) is shown preceeding the values:

[image]

Comment: Hey,
That's amazing, thank you.
Using your example, I then took the Result cell and referenced it in another sheet into a gap in the SQL script.
Then I used a VB script to export that to a file.
That's sorted it for me!

Thanks a lot!